# Get items from Redux store to React-select options

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-select

How to get items from my Redux store to React-select options?
Try many things, but i can't solve this problem. Try to get data by fetching api directly, it works, but doesn't work for me. In redux reducers i am fetching data from external json file to place project on sandbox, but actualy i am using my server api. On the list page data taken from redux Store, but I cant get it in Select options. Help please guys. Here is a sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-mountain-j5xft?file=/src/components/select.js) (choose "select")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async Select component requires a input to fetch the start fetching data. Also, it expects either invoking the `callback` or returning a Promise.

Modify `Select` as below

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
// Use the non-async version
import AsyncSelect from "react-select"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"

function Select() {
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState("")
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null)

  // useSelector will make sure this component re-renders
  const list = useSelector((s) => s.tasks.list)

  const handleInputChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value)
  }

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setSelectedValue(value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>React-Select Async Dropdown - </h3>
      <pre>Input Value: "{inputValue}"</pre>
      <AsyncSelect
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        options={list} // Since the list is provided by the store, provide it directly
        value={selectedValue}
        getOptionLabel={(e) => e.name}
        getOptionValue={(e) => e.id}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <pre>Selected Value: {JSON.stringify(selectedValue || {}, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Select
```

Comment: @olegoriginal, happy coding!

Comment: In case `AsyncSelect` is not rendering the options, you could change to `Select`.
My working version is `4.3.0`